# Word that describes interaction between things

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

The best word I've been able to come up with is *synergy*, but I'm pretty sure I'm using it wrong, and if I'm not, it isn't commonly used to describe this.

Here's my example case:

If I have an employee, I want a (somewhat common) word to describe all of the employee's interactions with managers and customers and vice-versa (i.e. it could be all of a single manager's interactions with customers and employees.)

Comment: _Interaction_ comes to mind

Comment: I'm looking for more of a buzzword

Comment: I don;t see the problem, as @mplungjan said, _interaction_ is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm looking for a word that means *to describe interactions*

Comment: Synonyms: http://thesaurus.com/browse/interaction

Comment: I've been on thesauruses already, but I figured it out

Comment: I up-voted you if only because no one, evidently, wants to own up to down-voting you.

Comment: Not my downvote, but reasons could be... not indicating any research (including unsatisfactory results, and explaining why they are unsuitable); not explaining what you want to use the word for (that is, an example sentence with a blank in it); not looking up [*synergy*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/synergy?q=synergy) to find out if you're using it right.

Comment: My downvote. For all of the above reasons.

Comment: "I'm looking for a word that means *to describe interactions*".    Really?  *I find it difficult to ___________ for one of my reports because she rarely interacts with anyone when I'm around, and yet her coworkers all say she is always willing to help and that she has a great sense of humor.*

Answer (score 0):

This may not be grammatically correct, but, the term "teaming" is used widely in the software industry to describe all sets of interactions across all levels (clients, subordinates, peers, superiors, collaborator, vendors) etc.

It has been in use for several years and is used in English-speaking countries as well.

Answer (score -1):

Some of the words that answer my question and apply to my example would be:

- fusion
- synthesis
- intersection
- mesh
- affiliation
- association
- junction